# Cloth flies away shortly after colliding with somthing

Tags: cloth-simulation

So I have this upsidedown ocean modifier plane exported as ABC, then imported back into blender with a solidify modifier added to it.

I'm trying to drop the cloth onto the animated ocean object but shortly after the object started moving, the cloth freaks out and flies away.

Please feel free to  ask for any additional info, and thanks in advance.

Blender file: [image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, so we can check it out. thx. and ...if i may be honest...it is not our task to ask you for info, but it is your task to provide all necessary infos if you ask this question. You want help, right? so you should make it as easy as possible for us who help for free in our spare time. thx.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad,  I didn't know you could upload blender files, I've uploaded the file just know!

Comment: i downloaded the file and it just keeps laying down - did u try deleting your cache?